# GWT requestFactory EntityProxy nesting

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Can i do that?

```
@ProxyFor(value = User.class, locator = EntityLocator.class)
  public interface UserProxy extends EntityProxy{

   List<UserProxy> getFriends();
}
```

I suppose that work, but i get null.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing a call to `with("friends")`.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#relationships